# Querying Google Spreadsheet by column name leads to error

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-query-language

I'm just getting started with using SQL and Google Spreadsheets. Using this spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/150EirFnWyKwb27PBXDvIRnhJkKm1q-Lgb3GgSHBm4jg

I can produce a simple page with all the results:

https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?tqx=out:html&tq=SELECT%20*&key=150EirFnWyKwb27PBXDvIRnhJkKm1q-Lgb3GgSHBm4jg&gid=0

But if I try to to select only certain columns (or filter), I get an error that there is no columned named X, where X is any column name I try.

For example, replace SELECT%20* with SELECT%20species in the above URL and you will see what I mean. Apparently, I can only post two links with a new account...

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column named X is not the name of your data in column, it's the letter of column.

this link works:

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?tqx=out:html&tq=SELECT%20A&key=150EirFnWyKwb27PBXDvIRnhJkKm1q-Lgb3GgSHBm4jg&gid=0
```

And gives column A output only.

And also this sintax works:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/150EirFnWyKwb27PBXDvIRnhJkKm1q-Lgb3GgSHBm4jg/gviz/tq?tqx=out:html&tq=SELECT+A+order+by+A&gid=0

with same result as

```
select A order by A
```